# ltrim doesn't return expected result with slashes

Tags: php, trim

i've a problem with "/anystring" and ltrim function in php.

here's my code:

```
$s = "/ciao/come/va";

$s1 = ltrim($s,'/ciao');

echo $s1;
```

i want `$s1` return `"/come/va"` but the code always returns `"me/va"`
I've already test other solution but i need to use ltrim.

Comment: Did you think about explode function?

Comment: if your format fix like this $s = "/ciao/come/va"; than you will do it in this way 
$s = "/ciao/come/va";
$s1 = explode("/", $s);
unset($s1[0]);
unset($s1[1]);
$s2 = implode("/", $s1);
echo $s2; 

beacuse when you use ltrim  and set character it will search "c" and "o" from other line and remove it also

must read and see examples carefully and you will get idea why its behave like this 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php